# jQuery check external image width

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, external

I'm on a little rss feed reader and I'd like to load to each article the first image to set that as main image.

```
function getNewsImage(content, request){
var $container = $('<div/>').html(content);

var result = {
     links:[],
     images:[]
}; 

$container.find('a[href],img').each(function() {
    if(this.tagName.toUpperCase() == 'A') {
        result.links.push([this.tagName,this.innerHTML,this.href]);
    } else {
        result.images.push([this.tagName,this.src,this.alt]);
    }
});

var image;

if(request=='link'){
  image = result.links[0][1];
}else{
  if(typeof result.images[0] !== 'undefined'){
    var img = document.createElement('img')
    img.src = result.images[0][1]
    img.onload = function() {
        if(this.width > 20){
            image = result.images[0][1];
            return false;
        }else{
            image = 'images/noImage.png';
            return false;
        }
    }
  }else{
    image = 'images/noImage.png';
  }

      return image;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't return anything. The problem is the function img.onload = function (){} doesn't change the value of the variable image...

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: FWIW, using consistent, clear code indentation is really very useful and shouldn't be considered optional. It helps *you* read the code, and in cases like this where you're asking people for help, it helps *them* read the code. Compare the above with: http://pastie.org/8140228

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of issues:

1. You have a race condition. You need to hook `onload` **before** setting `src`. Otherwise, by the time you hook up `onload`, the event may have already been fired. Just swap the two statements. *(Lurkers: See "More on #1" below if you think there's no race condition.)*
2. You're setting a local variable, `image`, from within your `onload` handler. And you're returning `image` from your `getNewsImage` function. But your `onload` handler will be called **after** your `getNewsImage` function returns, so the value it returns will be `undefined` in the case where you're waiting for the image. You'll have to modify `getNewsImage` to accept a callback that it calls when it has the image, it *can't* return it using `return`.

...and a side issue: If you end up using a link instead of an image, you set `image` to the link's HTML but you never return `image`. The `return image;` statement is *within* the `else` clause that only deals with images. (See my comment on the question about consistent, clear code indentation.)

---

> ...I'm struggling with the callback.. could you give me a hint on how to solve that?

Currently, your code calling `getNewsImage` presumably looks like this:

```
var image = getNewsImage(someContent, someRequest);
if (image.src) {
    doSomethingWithTheImage(image);
}
else {
    doSomethingWithTheLinkText(image);
}
// ...and so on...
```

You'd change it so that you used it like this:

```
getNewsImage(someContent, someRequest, function(image) {
    if (image.src) {
        doSomethingWithTheImage(image);
    }
    else {
        doSomethingWithTheLinkText(image);
    }
    // ...and so on...
});
```

Then the signature of `getNewsImage` changes to look like this:

```
function getNewsImage(content, request, callback){
// The new bit -----------------------^^^^^^^^^^
```

You never `return image;` anywhere in `getNewsImage`. Instead, you change it to call the passed-in callback and give that callback the image:

```
callback(image);
```

...and you make sure you always do that *asynchronously*.

E.g.:

```
function getNewsImage(content, request, callback) {
                      // Change -----^^^^^^^^^^^
  var $container = $('<div/>').html(content);

  var result = {
    links: [],
    images: []
  };

  var async = true;                               // <== Change

  $container.find('a[href],img').each(function () {
    if (this.tagName.toUpperCase() == 'A') {
      result.links.push([this.tagName, this.innerHTML, this.href]);
    }
    else {
      result.images.push([this.tagName, this.src, this.alt]);
    }
  });

  if (request == 'link') {
    done(result.links[0][1]);                     // <== Change
  }
  else {
    if (typeof result.images[0] !== 'undefined') {
      var img = document.createElement('img')
      img.onload = function () {
        async = false;                            // <== Change
        if (this.width > 20) {
          done(result.images[0][1]);              // <== Change
        }
        else {
          done('images/noImage.png');             // <== Change
        }
      }
      img.src = result.images[0][1];              // <== Change (moved under `onload`)
    }
    else {
      done('images/noImage.png');                 // <== Change
    }
  }

  // New (note this is *within* getNewsImage)
  function done(image) {
    if (async) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        callback(image);
      }, 0);
    }
    else {
      callback(image);
    }
  }
}
```

The contract is this: `getNewsImage` will call the callback, asynchronously, with the result. Note that in the above, even if we have the result synchronously, we schedule an asynchronous callback anyway; it's important that the contract be consistent, and since the callback will be asynchronous when `onload` is involved, we ensure it's *always* asynchronous (by using `setTimeout(..., 0)` if necessary).

---

More on #1:

Yes, for those wondering, the race condition **does** exist, even though JavaScript on browsers is single-threaded (barring use of web workers). The browser implementation is entirely within its rights to see the `img` `src` get set, see that the image is in cache, and queue callbacks for all `load` handlers on that image in its internal event queue (and since there are none, none get queued). It's not allowed to *trigger* those callbacks until the currently-running JavaScript yields back to the browser, but it's allowed to queue them, which is why we have the race.

Comment: Also, the return false only returns from the onload function, which is async, so getNewsImage() probably doesn't return what the OP thinks it does as the image variable is returned before it's changed in the onload handler?

Comment: Thank you for your response! I've changed the order of `onload` and `src` but I'm struggling with the callback.. could you give me a hint on how to solve that?

Comment: @DamianFrizzi: I've added to the answer.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot for your answer! I've implemented it and it works as you anticipated but it doesn't fit my purposes. I've uploaded my code on jsfiddle so you cann see how I use the image: http://jsfiddle.net/m3Y6c/1/ 
On line 103 is the request and on line 139 I'd like to give it out.. Unfortunately this doesn't work with the callback.